# Find and sort images by EXIF data (camera model) almost working

Tags: pipe, exec, xargs

As the title says I'm trying to sort images in folders depending what camera was used to take them. I've been working hard at learning how to use pipes and xargs and I think I'm almost there. The only problem is that the last xargs seems to be executed only once awk has gone though the whole folder and not for each file. If I do:

```
find temp/sorted/jpg_over_300px/ -type f -exec identify -quiet -format '%[EXIF:model] %i \n' '{}' \; | gawk '$2=="SE" {print $3}'
```

I get nice clean results, new lines as the files are found and the exif camera model matches "SE" for iPhone SE. But if I add an `xargs -I % mv % [new_folder]` command to move the files to a different folder the mv only gets executed once all the folder has been completely scanned (I know because I have tried with a folder containing only one file).

```
find temp/sorted/jpg_over_300px/ -type f -exec identify -quiet -format '%[EXIF:model] %i \n' '{}' \; | gawk '$2=="SE"{print $3}' | xargs -I % mv % temp/sorted/jpg_iphone_se/
```

I want to avoid that as there are A LOT of files in my folder and I want to avoid a "too many arguments" sort of situation. I have tried adding -print0 to find and -0 to xargs but no luck.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, thanks to [this question][https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336184/use-output-from-awk-as-input-for-mv]

I've also done some clean up and a redirection of stderr to only send valid requests to awk.

```
find temp/sorted/jpg_over_300px/ -type f -exec identify -format '%[EXIF:model] %i\n' '{}' \; 2> /dev/null | awk '/iPhone 5S/ {system("cp "$3" temp/sorted/jpg_iphone_5s")}'
```

For people who are learning like me, here it is step by step:

```
find temp/sorted/jpg_over_300px/ -type f -exec identify -format '%[EXIF:model] %i\n' '{}' \;
```

Use the command `find`, look into folder `temp/sorted/jpg_over_300px/` for files only `-type f` and everytime one is found execute the command identify `-exec identify` to extract the exif data regarding the model of the camera `-format '%[EXIF:model]'` and the name of the file '%i' plus a newline character `\n` to send properly formatted results to the rest of the pipe. Before moving on to the rest of the pipe we get rid of error messages by redirecting stderr to a black hole `2>/dev/null` then we pipe into awk `| awk` which will look for iPhone SE in the data transmitted through the pipe `'/iPhone 5S/` and execute the system command cp to copy the files to the new folder `{system("cp "$3" temp/sorted/jpg_iphone_5s")}'`